# AWS Kinesis Stream In Detail Review

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-kinesis

I am new to AWS. I have implemented some functionalities in aws using java. My requirement is to insert a csv of 50MB to RDS PostgreSQL instance at a time.

I tried with aws lmabda service. But after 5 minutes lambda will be stopped so i dropped that way.(Limitation of lambda function)

The second step I followed I wrote a java lambda code of s3 event which will read the csv file falls on s3 to a kinesis stream using putrecord command. According to my understanding, kinesis is capable of read csv file record by record. This kinesis stream will invoke a second lambda function which is saving data to postgreSQL.

Everything was fine. But my confusion is that only 32000 record is inserting. I have 50000 records in my csv. according to kinesis stream it will reading each row as a record so each time it will invoke lambda separately right? so why it is not saving completely?

One more question in my kinesis stream configured like below.
[image]

Also in my lambda i configured kinesis as

[image]

Is this the correct configuration for my requirement? if I give batchsize as 1 will my function insert the complete record?Please let me know ur knowledge about this. It would be a great help from you thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exceeding your limits for a single shard.

Review the following document:
[Amazon Kinesis Data Streams Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html)

Make sure that your code is checking for errors on each AWS call.

Comment: Thanks @John Hanley for your favorable reply.  I checked the link earlier also. You mean that i need to increase my open shard resource from 1 to maximum number? sorry if the question is irrelevant...

Comment: Yes, you need to increase the number of shards. Start with 5 or 10 and then retest. Tune the number. The key is the number of records and MB per second that you are pumping into Kinesis.